# Loop over file names from `find`?

Tags: linux, shell, loops, find

If I run this command:

```
sudo find . -name *.mp3
```

then I can get a listing of lots of mp3 files.

Now I want to do something with each mp3 file in a loop.  For example, I could create a `while` loop, and inside assign the first file name to the variable `file`.  Then I could do something with that file.  Next I could assign the second file name to the variable `file` and do with that, etc.

How can I realize this using a linux shell command? Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: All the solutions not involving `-exec` or `xargs -0` are doomed to fall (and fail) under shell word splitting rules and/or reek of so-called “useless use of cat” issues.

Comment: Excuse me, but why do not I see a word splitting problem in this, as you would say "doomed to fail", solution: echo -e 'hello.txt\nmy picture.jpg' | while read line; do echo reading line \"$line\"; done ?

Comment: There are a variety of solutions explained on Unix & Linux Stack Exchange: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/110402/62291 and http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/9496/62291

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For this, use the `read` builtin:

```
sudo find . -name *.mp3 |
while read filename
do
    echo "$filename"    # ... or any other command using $filename
done
```

Provided that your filenames don't use the newline (`\n`) character, this should work fine.

Comment: You can use `-print0` option for find and `-d ''` option for read to get around the `\n` issue. Also, use `-r` option for read so backslashes in the filename are not interpreted as escape sequences.

Comment: Sorry but, why `sudo`? Apart from being useless, it is dangerous and may not work with user bound sound infrastructures (i.e. pulseaudio)

Comment: @iMil: simply because it was given like that in the question.

Answer (score 11):

My favourites are

```
find . -name '*.mp3' -exec cmd {} \;
```

or

```
find . -name '*.mp3' -print0 | xargs -0 cmd
```

---

#### While Loop

As others have pointed out, you can frequently use a `while read` loop to read filenames line by line, it has the drawback of not allowing line-ends in filenames (who uses that?).

#### `xargs` vs. `-exec cmd {} +`

Summarizing the comments saying that `-exec`...`+` is better, I prefer xargs because it is more versatile:

- works with other commands than just `find`
- allows 'batching' (grouping) in command lines, say `xargs -n 10` (ten at a time)
- allows parallellizing, say `xargs -P4` (max 4 concurrent processes running at a time)
- does privilige separation (such as in the OP's case, where he uses `sudo find`: using `-exec` would run all commands as the root user, whereas with `xargs` that isn't necessary:

  ```
  sudo find -name '*.mp3' -print0 | sudo xargs -0 require_root.sh
  sudo find -name '*.mp3' -print0 | xargs -0 nonroot.sh
  ```
- in general, pipes are just more versatile (logging, sorting, remoting, caching, checking, parallelizing etc, you can do that)

Comment: `{} +` is better in relation to `{} ;`. `{} ;` is equivalent to `xargs -n1`. `{} +` can — like xargs, yes — pass in multiple files as arguments, but without having to spawn the extra xargs process, though on the counterside you don't get to change the symbol as you can with `xargs -I`. So there's that :)

Comment: If using `-exec`, you should really place the `{}` inside double quotes in case the file name contains spaces or other special characters.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg No: the (double) quotes never even reach `find`: the shell interprets them before that time. `find -exec` does the right thing anyway (it doesn't use the shell but something like [execvp](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execvp).

Comment: Downvoting as no $file variable involved which was mentioned in the task.

Comment: Alright, alright, I agree this is not a wrong solution. Pity I can't remove the vote down. :-(

Comment: thx, `-exec` works perfect ,but i need a `while` loop to do with lots of codes :)

Answer (score 2):

How about using the `-exec` option to find?

```
find . -name '*.mp3' -exec mpg123 '{}' \;
```

That will call the command `mpg123` for every file found, i.e. it will play all the files, in the order they are found.

Answer (score -2):

```
for file in $(sudo find . -name *.mp3);
do
    # do something with file
done
```

Comment: didn't downvote, but this works badly for filenames with special characters (like spaces)

Comment: yes.. I usually use it with my files that never had special characters except underscores in the names.. Your solution is fool-proof. Thanks!