# Is there a way to suppress the "The type (...) collides with a package" warning in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

This question is closely related to [java-class-name-same-as-the-nested-package-name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9584086/java-class-name-same-as-the-nested-package-name/9584358#9584358). My specific question here is: How can I disable/suppress that warning in Eclipse?

Some remarks:

- I cannot change the code, it's a pattern widely used by Jenkins.
- It seems the Java Language Specification (JLS) allows it - anyway javac doesn't mark it as error.
- The reason for the warning is that a class and a resource folder have the same name (I am not sure if a resource folder establishes a package according to JLS).
- I want to get that warning away because it hides other warnings.

Comment: which version of Eclipse and Jenikns are you using?

Comment: Since it is a warning in Eclipse you can check the settings to disable it. Should be somewhere in a "Inspections" menu (don't the real name of it since I don't use Eclipse).

Comment: Eclipse: Version: Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1)
Build id: 20140925-1800, Jenkins: current master (but that's not relevant, you can reproduce it with a simple example)

Comment: The warning is not listed under Java/Compiler/"Errors/Warnings" (or at least I am not able to find it there).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not currently possible to disable that warning in Eclipse. There is [an open feature request to make it possible](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=377850), however it has had no action since 2012.

Answer (score -1):

For Jenkins plugins, since there are no resources to compile in src/main/resources, in Eclipse, I toggled the 'Ignore optional compile problems' to Yes.   That will remove the warning.