# Compilation with javac fails, with eclipse-compiler it works

Tags: java, eclipse, javac

I'm trying to write a simple ant build to compile a project.
The project is in eclipse and there it compiles successfully (with the eclipse-compiler).
But with ant (using javac) it appears an error and i don't know how to resolve it.

**Structure of the used jar:**

- com

  - xxx

    - a <= package

      - b
    - a.class

**Codeblock of my class:**

```
Object o = com.xxx.a.b.method();
                    ^
```

**The exception of ant is:**

> error: cannot find symbol
>
> symbol:   variable b
>
> location: class a

I think eclipse uses the package first to try to compile the code. javac seems to think that a is the class.

Is there a way to resolve the problem without changing the jar?

Comment: maybe you should abide to the Java convention: class names start with uppercase, packages all lowercase...I just found: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9584086/85421

Comment: This sounds like `javac` vs. Eclipse compiler and has nothing to do with Ant. Is it possible to reproduce this issue with `javac` on the command line (and if so, with which JDK version)?

Comment: I tried it with pure javac. Same error. So ant has nothing to do with it. I'm using Java 8.

Comment: Update the title of this question, and remove such ambiguities from your sources.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like either package name is different or you have multiple class files of the same name. I would suggest checking the import statements and adding the specific jar file to classpath while compiling using javac or ant command.

To find the exact jar file, use `ctrl+T` then paste your class name in the box and it will tell you the jar file. Add that jar file to your ant classpath and build.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find anything in the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/index.html) that this is an error, so it might be a `javac` bug.

Since it is a **`javac` vs. Eclipse compiler** thing, try one of the following:

- [Use the **Eclipse compiler in the Ant** script](https://help.eclipse.org/photon/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/task-ant_javac_adapter.htm)
- If it is a `javac` bug, the bug may be fixed in a **newer (update) JDK version**
- If your code does not directly reference class `com.xxx.a`, **compile** the code with the **JAR in which the class `com.xxx.a` was removed**

Comment: Positively speaking, JLS sections §6.5.1 and §6.5.5.2 should allow correctly resolving a known-to-be-typename to the desired type. I tried a few examples where javac and ecj seem to agree on ignoring these rules. In cases like this JLS seems to be overruled by reality. If OTOH a difference between compilers is detected, a fix towards the specified behavior in one of the compilers should be more likely. Hence: is there a case where compilers _disagree_?